# como pegar archivo Json escrapeado en otro JavaScript para poderlo manipularlo directamente?

Tags: javascript, scraping

tengo esta función para escrapear una tabla, esto me crea un archivo Json que me es actualizado cada cierto tiempo, y tengo la otra parte del código que me lo lee y lo convierte en objeto, pero quiero este archivo me aparezca directamente en el archivo js para manipularlo directamente.

```
// ANTIOQUEÑITA-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

setInterval(function(){

scrapper.get( "https://loteriasdehoy.co/antioquenita-1").then((data1) => {
  fs.writeFile("antioquenita.json", JSON.stringify(data1), function (err, res) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
  return data1;
});

const antioquenita = './antioquenita.json'

try {
  fs.unlinkSync(antioquenita)
  //file removed
} catch(err) {
  console.error(err)
}

},600*1000)
```

el anterior es un index.js Y luego para intentarlo editar en otro  antioqueñita,js.

```
var salida = require("./antioquenita.json");

//console.log(salida);

var nuevoArreglo = salida.map(function (o) {
  return Object.keys(o).reduce(function (array, key) {
    return array.concat([key, o[key]]);
  }, []);
});

console.log(nuevoArreglo);

var na = nuevoArreglo.forEach(contenido => contenido.forEach(dentro => console.log(dentro)));
console.log(na);

var na1 = na.slice(0,50)
console.log(na1.Resultado);
```

Comment: Pues junta el código en uno solo, poniendo el  antioqueñita.js dentro del index.js y en lugar de guardarlo en un archivo lo vuelcas sobre la variable **salida**, quitando todo lo que haga referencia a la gestión de archivos. Por ejemplo: `var salida = JSON.stringify(data1)` y a partir de ahí que continue con el resto del código de antioqueñita.js tal como ya lo tenias.

Comment: Quiero ejecutar cada sorteo por aparte, implica tener un index.js que se encarga de scrapear cada sorteo generando los diferentes Json en la misma carpeta del archivo; y otros js de cada sorteo, para ejecutar con cada Json generado análisis numéricos, es por esto que requiero tener cada elemento por aparte.